# HTTP 500 Error while uploading image in php CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, hosting, web-hosting

I am new at php CodeIgniter(3.1.4) framework. now i am working in a project. In my project i need to upload a image. I have written a method for uploading an image. It's work perfectly on my localhost. but while i host my project in my website(shared hosting), i have got an 500 error. I am giving my code and file structure permission below.
File Permission: application(0755), assets(0755), uploads(0755)

code->
controller:

```
public function save_carousel_image() {
    if (!empty($this->session->userdata('user_session'))) {
        $path = '';
        $new_name = $_FILES["image"]['name'];
        $config['file_name'] = $new_name;
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/carousel_images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = 2048;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $carousel_image_name = trim($this->input->post('carousel_image_name'));
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo 'You did not select a file to upload.';
        } else {
            $carousel_image_name = trim($this->input->post('carousel_image_name'));
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $path = 'assets/uploads/carousel_images/' . $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
            $data = array(
                'carousel_image_name' => $carousel_image_name,
                'carousel_image_path' => $path
            );
            $this->Carousel_image_Model->db->insert('carousel_image', $data);
            redirect(base_url('admin/carousel_image'));
        }
    } else {
        redirect(base_url('admin/user_login'));
    }
}
```

view->

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
        <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
        <span>Upload File</span>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="readURL(this)"  >
    </span>
</div><div class="card" style="background-color: white;">
    <img id="bannerImage" src="" height="300px" width="300px">
</div><script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#bannerImage').addClass('image-preview');
            $('#bannerImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you read error logs for detail description of 500 error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353468/2275490

Comment: I have read the apache2 error logs and its showing "POST /captain_cool/admin/carousel_image/save_carousel_image HTTP/1.1" 500 20 "http://www.captaincool-fh.com/captain_cool/admin/carousel_image/create_new_carousel_image" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"  @u_mulder ..Can you please help me out.

Comment: When i click on save button to save image. it shows me 
This page isn’t working
captaincool-fh.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 @kirk Beard Can you help me.