# Api upload file using curl in codeigniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, curl, file-upload

I need help guys,
I have some api to upload a file.But, i haven't experience adout it.

What i do first is create a view and controller to upload my file to a folder,here my code:

View

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo site_url('stepfour/adduploadExcel') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
          <label for="exampleInputFile"><a href="#">Excel Template Format Sample</a></label>
          <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="product_benefit_data">
          <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and here my controller look like:

```
          public function adduploadExcel()
          {
            $config['upload_path']          = './upload/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'xls|xlsx';
            $config['max_size']             = 10000;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('product_benefit_data')){
              redirect('stepthree/viewstepthree');
            }else{
              $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
              $data = array (
                    "product_id"      => $this->input->post('product_id'),
                    "currency_id"       => $this->input->post('codeexclusion')
                  );
              $jsonData = json_encode($data);
              $this->uploadApi($jsonData);
              // redirect('stepfour/viewstepfour');

            }
          }


and this api that i want to hit using php curl:

  public function uploadApi($jsonData)
  {
    $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $accessToken = $sessionData['access_token'];
    $headers     = array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Authorization: Bearer '.$accessToken
    );


      $uploadDir = base_url('upload/');
        $uploadFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['product_benefit_data']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_benefit_data']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile))
        {
          $uploadRequest = array(
              'fileName' => basename($uploadFile),
              'fileData' => base64_encode(fopen($uploadFile))
            );


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://development.dev/api/product');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

        $curl_exec  = curl_exec($ch);
        $result   = json_decode($curl_exec, TRUE);
        $httpcode   = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if($httpcode == 200)
        {
          $msg['success'] = 'Upload Success!';
          $this->load->view('back/vheader');
          $this->load->view('back/product/vstepfour',$msg);
          $this->load->view('back/vfooter');
        } elseif ($httpcode == 500) {
          $msg['failed'] = 'Upload Fail!';
          $this->load->view('back/vheader');
          $this->load->view('back/product/vstepfour',$msg);
          $this->load->view('back/vfooter');
        }
        }else{
          echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
        }


  }
```

I learn using this step look like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776859/php-upload-image-to-remote-server-with-curl), but i got error like this:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:
>   move_uploaded_file(http://personal-web/devebb/upload/Business_Flow.xlsx):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable
>   connections
>
> Filename: controllers/Stepfour.php
>
> Line Number: 119
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\personal\devebb\application\controllers\Stepfour.php
>   Line: 119 Function: move_uploaded_file
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\personal\devebb\application\controllers\Stepfour.php
>   Line: 101 Function: uploadApi
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\personal\devebb\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: localhost on local machine or shared hosting?

Comment: my source will upload to hosting, but now testing upload on local but api url is on shared hosting @Vickel

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353468/2275490