# Could not upload file with codeigniter do_upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

My problem is that I have a code that works on localhost but not on production server. I want to upload a file through a form. In localhost everything works fine, but on production server, I get the 'you did not select a file to upload' error.

The view part

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Ajax/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload image" />
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

The controller part (controller Ajax, function do_upload)

```
public function do_upload(){

    $config['upload_path']          = './assets/images/usr_uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']             = 5000;
    $config['max_width']            = 2048;
    $config['max_height']           = 2048;
    $config['overwrite']           = true;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")){
        //$data['error'] = "An error occurred while uploading the image.";
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        //echo $filename;
        print_r($_FILES);
        $this->load->view('template/head.php');
        $this->load->view('profileview.php', $error);
        $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
    } else {
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $data['up_ok'] = $filename;
        print_r($_FILES);
        $this->savefn($filename);
        $this->updatesesssion();
        $this->load->view('template/head.php');
        $this->load->view('profileview.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer.php');
    }
}
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

So the problem is that when on production server, it does not get any file from the form. On localhost it works as it should. I cannot find the cause of this problem and I have tried almost everything I have found. I have also tried with the default userfile, which again works on localhost but not on server and I have already set the folder permissions to 777.

Comment: Is `$config['base_url']` value set well? `.htaccess` too?

Comment: base_url is fine. htaccess file: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: Please copy that and edit your question with code tags to be readable.

Comment: You only need to load config one remove this `$this->upload->initialize($config);`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I did and it does not work

Comment: @Tpojka
htaccess file 
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: I edited your question already. What is value of base_url?

Comment: Where is project set - in web root directory?

Comment: `$config['base_url'] = 'my domain/';` @Tpojka it just contains the domain

Comment: @Tpojka yes it is a codeigniter project in root directory

Comment: Ensure it is `'http://example.com/' or 'https://example.com/' with included scheme. Put `RewriteBase /` in youe *.htaccess* file just after `RewriteEngine On` part.

Comment: @Tpojka I did it, still does not work

Comment: Is just that URL doesn't work or you didn't check the rest ones? Try with index.php in URL (i.e. put back `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` in config file).

Comment: @Tpojka the rest works for me. Just this thing with the upload does not work

Comment: Form helper is loaded?

Comment: @Tpojka yes it's loaded

Comment: Make another controller / view with **exact** code from [docs' example](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) to check if it is working that way.

Comment: @Tpojka ok may try it later

Comment: please read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353468/2275490

Answer (score 0):

I think your domain is not fetching at live server. use ip address or below global variable $_SERVER
try to change `$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Suggest adding a description of what it does and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known this function, try change `$this->savefn($filename);` to 

`$image = $this->upload->data();
print_r($image['file_name']);`