# Cropped image encrypted data not post in codeigniter on live server. Why?

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, cropperjs

I have a situation where a user select photo and cropped it.After cropping encoded data passed to hidden input has successfully but when posting my form the image data not post.Only blank page shown.

Same code are working fine on local server. But on live server this happened to me.

Let me share my code. Please guide me where i am doing wrong.

```js
$(".gambar").attr("src", "<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/users/defualt.jpg");
  var $uploadCrop,
  tempFilename,
  rawImg,
  imageId;
  function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('.upload-demo').addClass('ready');
        $('#cropImagePop').modal('show');
              rawImg = e.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        else {
          swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
      }
  }

  $uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    viewport: {
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      type: 'circle'
    },
    boundary: {
      width: 265,
      height: 265
    },
    enforceBoundary: false,
    enableExif: true,
    enableOrientation: true,
    orientation: 4,
  });
  $('#cropImagePop').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
          url: rawImg
        }).then(function(){
        });
  });

  $('.item-img').on('change', function () { 
    imageId = $(this).data('id'); 
    tempFilename = $(this).val();
    $('#cancelCropBtn').data('id', imageId); 
    readFile(this); });
  $('#cropImageBtn').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
      type: 'canvas',
      format: 'jpeg',
      size: {width: 150, height: 150}
    }).then(function (resp) {
      $('#imageEncoder').val(resp);
      $('#item-img-output').attr('src', resp);
      $('#cropImagePop').modal('hide');
      $('#profile_form').submit();
    });
  });
```

```html
<form action="<?= base_url().'userController/update_staff_picture' ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="profile_form">
      <input type="hidden" name="imageEncoder" id="imageEncoder">
      <label class="cabinet center-block">
       <figure>
        <img src="" class="gambar img-responsive img-thumbnail img-circle" id="item-img-output" />
         <figcaption><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></figcaption>
       </figure>
       <input type="file" class="item-img file center-block" name="file_photo"/>
      </label>
    </form>
```

**User Controller**

```
public function update_staff_picture(){

        $data = $this->input->post('imageEncoder');

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        exit();
        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);
        $image_name = date('ymdgis').'.png';
        $req['image']=$image_name;


        file_put_contents('./assets/img/users/'.$image_name, $data);

        $this->db->set($req);
        $this->db->where('userID',$userID);
        $this->db->update('users');

        redirect(base_url().'staff-profile/'.$_POST['userID']);

}
```

Comment: I see you have added a `print_r` to the upload controller. good troubleshooting step. have you pushed this copy to the live server to see what the result is?

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41353468/2275490

Comment: @Alex the result is blank page.

Comment: is it really blank? or is `<pre>` there in the source?